# Predicted values for conditional logistic regression greater than 1

Tags: r, conditional-statements, regression, matching, predict

I have a multivariate conditional logistic regression model. Case and controls are matched on a 1 to many basis.

I want to make predictions using the model. However, the predicted values I keep getting are between 0 and 3 when they should be binary (0 or 1). Why don't I get binary values?

This is my data:
survival1 is binary.
IC is also binary.
Test_intensity-cat is categorical with 4 levels.
Herd_size_cat is also categorical with 4 levels.
Group has groups in the original data set. I've just included 11 here. The subset of data doesn't converge but the original set does.

```
n   survival1   IC   test_intensity_cat herd_size_cat group
1          0 none  1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5        medium   628
2          0 none       <= 1.2 test/yr        medium   629
3          0 none        >= 2 tests/yr    very large   627
4          1   IC        >= 2 tests/yr    very large   628
5          0 none       <= 1.2 test/yr         large   627
6          1   IC        >= 2 tests/yr    very large   627
7          1 none        >= 2 tests/yr    very large   627
8          0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2         large   629
9          0   IC   1.5 < test/yr <= 2    very large   629
10         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2         large   628
11         0 none       <= 1.2 test/yr         large   628
12         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2         small   231
13         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2    very large   231
14         0 none 1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5    very large   231
15         0   IC   1.5 < test/yr <= 2    very large   231
16         1 none        >= 2 tests/yr    very large   170
17         0 none 1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5    very large   170
18         0 none        >= 2 tests/yr    very large   170
19         1 none        >= 2 tests/yr        medium   582
20         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2         small   583
21         0   IC   1.5 < test/yr <= 2         large   582
22         1 none        >= 2 tests/yr         large   583
23         0 none 1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5    very large   134
24         0 none 1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5    very large   134
25         0 none       <= 1.2 test/yr         small   134
26         0   IC   1.5 < test/yr <= 2    very large   134
27         0 none 1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5    very large   484
28         0 none        >= 2 tests/yr    very large   485
29         0   IC   1.5 < test/yr <= 2        medium   484
30         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2         large   485
31         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2         small   484
32         0   IC       <= 1.2 test/yr    very large   485
33         0 none 1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5    very large   484
34         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2    very large   485
35         0 none       <= 1.2 test/yr        medium    76
36         0 none        >= 2 tests/yr    very large    76
37         0 none        >= 2 tests/yr         large    76
38         0   IC        >= 2 tests/yr        medium    76
39         0 none       <= 1.2 test/yr    very large   629
40         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2        medium   582
41         0   IC        >= 2 tests/yr         large   170
42         1   IC 1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5         small   583
43         0 none   1.5 < test/yr <= 2         small   582
44         0 none       <= 1.2 test/yr         small   583
```

This is my code is in R studio:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
library(survival)

model_IC_intensity_size <-
clogit(survival1 ~ IC + test_intensity_cat + herd_size_cat + strata(group),
method = "exact",
data = LCT_herd_matched)

actual <- LCT_herd_matched$survival1
predicted <- round(predict(model_IC_intensity_size, type = "expected"))
table(predicted, actual)
```

This is the output with the original dataset. The subset gives a smaller version that includes an aberrant 2.

```
           actual
predicted    0    1
        0 9271  641
        1  185  434
        2    6   42
        3    0    2
```

I'm also want to calculate leverage, delta chi squared and the delta beta statistics (p 425 Veterinary Epidemiologic Research by Dohoo et al). How would I go about determining these diagnostics for a conditional logistic regression model in R?

```
dput(mini)
structure(list(survival1 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), IC = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("none", "IC"
), class = "factor"), test_intensity_cat = structure(c(3L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("<= 1.2 test/yr", 
">= 2 tests/yr", "1.2 < test/yr <= 1.5", "1.5 < test/yr <= 2"
), class = "factor"), herd_size_cat = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("small", "medium", 
"large", "very large"), class = "factor"), group = structure(c(627L, 
628L, 626L, 627L, 626L, 626L, 626L, 628L, 628L, 627L, 627L, 231L, 
231L, 231L, 231L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 581L, 582L, 581L, 582L, 134L, 
134L, 134L, 134L, 483L, 484L, 483L, 484L, 483L, 484L, 483L, 484L, 
76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 628L, 581L, 170L, 582L, 581L, 582L), .Label = 
c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
"36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", 
"47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", 
"80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", 
"91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", 
"101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", 
"110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", 
"119", "120", "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", 
"128", "129", "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", 
"137", "138", "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", 
"146", "147", "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", 
"155", "156", "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", 
"164", "165", "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", 
"173", "174", "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", 
"182", "183", "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", 
"191", "192", "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", 
"200", "201", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", 
"209", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", 
"218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", 
"227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", 
"236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "241", "242", "243", "244", 
"245", "246", "247", "248", "249", "250", "251", "252", "253", 
"254", "255", "256", "257", "258", "259", "260", "261", "262", 
"263", "264", "265", "266", "267", "268", "269", "270", "271", 
"272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "280", "281", 
"282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", 
"291", "292", "293", "294", "295", "296", "297", "298", "299", 
"300", "301", "302", "303", "304", "305", "306", "307", "308", 
"309", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314", "315", "316", "317", 
"318", "319", "320", "321", "322", "323", "324", "325", "326", 
"327", "328", "329", "330", "331", "332", "333", "334", "335", 
"336", "337", "338", "339", "340", "341", "342", "343", "344", 
"345", "346", "347", "348", "349", "350", "351", "352", "353", 
"354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "359", "360", "361", "362", 
"363", "364", "365", "366", "367", "368", "369", "370", "371", 
"372", "373", "374", "375", "376", "377", "378", "379", "380", 
"381", "382", "383", "384", "385", "386", "387", "388", "389", 
"390", "391", "392", "393", "394", "395", "396", "397", "398", 
"399", "400", "401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", "407", 
"408", "409", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414", "415", "416", 
"417", "418", "419", "420", "421", "422", "423", "424", "425", 
"426", "427", "428", "429", "430", "431", "432", "433", "434", 
"435", "436", "437", "438", "439", "440", "441", "442", "443", 
"444", "445", "446", "447", "448", "449", "450", "451", "452", 
"453", "454", "455", "456", "457", "458", "459", "460", "461", 
"462", "463", "464", "465", "466", "467", "468", "469", "470", 
"471", "472", "473", "474", "475", "476", "477", "478", "479", 
"480", "481", "482", "483", "484", "485", "486", "487", "488", 
"489", "490", "491", "492", "493", "494", "495", "496", "497", 
"498", "499", "500", "501", "502", "503", "504", "505", "506", 
"507", "508", "509", "510", "511", "512", "513", "514", "515", 
"516", "517", "518", "519", "520", "521", "522", "523", "524", 
"525", "526", "527", "528", "529", "530", "531", "532", "533", 
"534", "535", "536", "537", "538", "539", "540", "541", "542", 
"543", "544", "545", "546", "547", "548", "549", "550", "551", 
"552", "553", "554", "555", "556", "557", "558", "559", "560", 
"561", "562", "563", "564", "565", "566", "567", "568", "569", 
"570", "571", "572", "573", "574", "575", "576", "577", "578", 
"579", "580", "581", "582", "583", "584", "585", "586", "587", 
"588", "589", "590", "591", "592", "593", "594", "595", "596", 
"597", "598", "599", "600", "601", "602", "603", "604", "605", 
"606", "607", "608", "609", "610", "611", "612", "613", "614", 
"615", "616", "617", "618", "619", "620", "621", "622", "623", 
"624", "625", "626", "627", "628", "629", "630", "631", "632", 
"633", "635", "636", "637", "638", "639", "640", "641", "642", 
"643", "644", "645", "646", "647", "648", "649", "650", "651", 
"652", "653", "654", "655", "656", "657", "658", "659", "660", 
"661", "662", "663", "664", "665", "666", "667", "668", "669", 
"670", "671", "672", "673", "674", "675", "676", "677", "678", 
"679", "680", "681", "682", "683", "684", "685", "686", "687", 
"688", "689", "690", "691", "692", "693", "694", "695", "696", 
"697", "698", "699", "700", "701", "702", "703", "704", "705", 
"706", "707", "708", "709", "710", "711", "712", "713", "714", 
"715", "716", "717", "718", "719", "720", "721", "722", "723", 
"724", "725", "726", "727", "728", "729", "730", "731", "732", 
"733", "734", "745", "746", "747", "748", "749", "750", "751", 
"752", "753", "754", "755", "756", "757", "758", "759", "760", 
"761", "762", "763", "764", "765", "766", "767", "986", "987"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: We can not reproduce your error unless we have some example data e.g. using `dput(head(LCT_herd_matched))`

Comment: Please include any packages or dependencies used in this analysis

Comment: I've added a subset of data. The model now gets a warning about not converging but that is just due to subset of data being small. the original dataset has 10,581 obs and 756 groups so converged without an issue.

Comment: Hi Hannah, is this the output of calling `dput()` ? The data is there but not in a format that is easy for others to paste into R. If you created that subset, calling that function should give us the code to re-create the data and run your code

Comment: The dput() output is at the very end

Answer (score 2):

I work in a different field but encountered similar issues when making predictions from `clogit` models. It appears there's different schools of thought on whether making predictions is even valid from these models (see comments in this thread [How to get fitted values from clogit model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329585/how-to-get-fitted-values-from-clogit-model)). Nevertheless, we attempted Terry Therneu's workaround presented in the above link. Although I can't reproduce you're data, below is a hypothetical and generic example of what we did. Essentially, we averaged predictions across strata. Would be interested in commentary from experts of which I am not one.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(survival)

dat <- data.frame(event = c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1),
                  strata = factor(c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5)),
                  cont_var1 = c(100, 90, 10, 20, 60, 95, 85, 15, 25, 65, 90, 80,
                                20, 30, 70, 100, 90, 10, 20, 60, 90, 80, 20, 30, 70),
                  cat_var = factor(c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b",
                                     "b","b","b","b","b","b","a","a","a","a","a")))

m1 <- clogit(event ~ cont_var1 + cat_var + strata(strata), data = dat, iter.max = 100)

# new dataframe 
newdat <- expand_grid(cont_var1 = seq(20, 100, 1), 
                      cat_var = factor(c("a"),
                                       levels = c("a", "b")),
                      strata = strata(unique(dat$strata)))
# predict
pred_dat <- newdat %>%
  bind_cols(predict(m1,
                    newdata = newdat,
                    type = "risk",
                    se.fit = TRUE))

# plot (note first step calculating probability from predictions)
pred_dat %>%
  mutate(prob = fit / (1 + fit),
         low = (fit - 1.96 * se.fit) / (1 + (fit - 1.96 * se.fit)),
         up = (fit + 1.96 * se.fit) / (1 + (fit + 1.96 * se.fit)),
         low = ifelse(low < 0, 0, low),
         up = ifelse(up > 1, 1, up)) %>%
  group_by(cont_var1) %>%
  summarise(prob = mean(prob), low = mean(low), up = mean(up)) %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x = cont_var1, y = prob)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = cont_var1, y = prob, ymin = low, ymax = up), alpha = 0.1) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) + 
  labs(y = "Probability (level 'a')", x = "Continuous Variable")
```